# Run local PHP tests against remote PHP server

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have the following setup:

Locally PhpStorm configured for remote debugging: SSH tunnel on port 9001, PhpStorm listening on 9001. I am able to debug the codebase, the connection works.

A remote Apache server with Xdebug configured to serve on 9001, 9001 is connected to my local 9001 via SSH tunnel.

The flow I am trying to accomplish is:

- in PhpStorm navigate to the test file
- add a breakpoint
- hit Debug button in PhpStorm

The application I am trying to debug has a setup that allows it to work only on a remote server, I cannot debug it nor the tests locally (it needs a dedicated public IP, which my local machine doesn't have.)

It is a complicated setup, that's why I decided to ask you. Is it possible to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, should be possible if you have a copy of a code base locally. Check out https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/

Comment: Remove thanks as per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it